# Prototype: Find all elements with a certain class and a certain style?

Tags: prototypejs

How can I find all elements with a class and a certain style? I know how to get all elements that have a certain class:

```
var elems = $$('.validation-advice');
```

How can I also say that only those that have the style="display:none;" as style should be selected? I know there is the visible function in Prototype, but somehow I cant get it to work. In the end I want to know if there are visible elements with the class validation-advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

using the CSS selector method `$$()` you can also do this

```
$$('.validation-advice[style~="display:none;"]')
```

the ~= means contains so your milage may vary on how reliable this selector is